# form of the addition with exponent $m^0+m^1+…+m^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series of addition $m^0+m^1+m^2+…+m^{n-1}$ for natural numbers $m$ and $n$. is there a simplified formula for this? How its related to $m^n$?

Comment: What you have here is a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Comment: @OldJohn Thanks I was missing this keyword. The form is $\frac{1-m^n}{1-m}$

Comment: You are welcome - glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a geometric series that you posted here.
so for a Geometric series(GP series) we have a closed formula.
so now let us have a look: if we have a series such as...
 a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ... + ar^n   (note that all the powers are only for 'r' not for 'a')
if anyone ask for the sum for this series then we can say that the sum is S= a(((r^n)-1)/(r-1)).note that here 'a' is the first term and the value 'r' is the ration of any two consecutive term of the series.hope this discussion will help you.best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Multiply your sum with $m-1$, and see what you get. :-)

Comment: I got $m^n-1$ :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend the formula I have given to here as S= a((r^n)-1)/(r-1) it is correct but it holds only when the value of 'r' is greater than 1 but if the value of 'r' is less than 1 or the value of 'r' is a fraction then the formula will be like this(all same but the denominator part will be (1-r)) S= a(((r^n)-1)/(1-r)).
sorry friend for my last answer.I should give this formula as well.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: you can edit your existed answer instead of creating a new one :)